# Python - Match variable regex including double brackets

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame 'df' and a list of strings 'l'. I want to iterate through the list and find the rows of the DataFrame matching with strings from the list. 
Following code works fine if there are no brackets in the list elements. It seems like the regex is not defined properly and somehow the double brackets are not getting matched.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {'col1': ['100-(abc)','qwe-100-(abc)', '100-(abc)1', 
              'xyz', 'xyz2', 'zzz'], 
     'col2': ['100', '1001','200', '300', '400', '500']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

lst = ['100-(abc)', 'xyz']

for l in lst:
    print("======================")
    pattern = re.compile(r"(" + l + ")$")
    print(df[df.col1.str.contains(pattern, regex=True)])
```

result:

```
======================
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
======================
  col1 col2
3  xyz  300
```

**Expected result:**

```
======================
  col1           col2
0  100-(abc)     100
1  qwe-100-(abc) 1001

======================
  col1 col2
3  xyz  300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that:

> Regex have some reserve certain characters for special use the opening
>   parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), are one of them.

If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash. If you want to match `1+1=2`, the correct regex is `1\+1=2`. Otherwise, the plus sign has a special meaning.
Same with parenthesis , if you want to match `(abc)` you have to do `\(abc\)`

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {'col1': ['100-(abc)','qwe-100-(abc)', '100-(abc)1',
              'xyz', 'xyz2', 'zzz'],
     'col2': ['100', '1001','200', '300', '400', '500']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

lst = ['100-(abc)', 'xyz']


for l in lst:
    print("======================")
    if '(' in l:
        match=l.replace('(','\(').replace(')','\)')
        pattern = r"(" + match + ")$"
        print(df[df.col1.str.contains(pattern, regex=True)])
    else:
        pattern = r"(" + l + ")$"
        print(df[df.col1.str.contains(pattern, regex=True)])
```

output:

```
            col1  col2
0      100-(abc)   100
1  qwe-100-(abc)  1001
======================
  col1 col2
3  xyz  300
```

Comment: I can not change the list strings. Actual dataset ie large and i dont want to mess with it. I am looking for a generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use isin

```
df[df.col1.isin(lst)]


    col1        col2
0   100-(abc)   100
3   xyz         300
```

Edit:
Add in a regex pattern along with isin

```
df[(df.col1.isin(lst)) | (df.col1.str.contains('\d+-\(.*\)$', regex = True))]
```

You get

```
    col1            col2
0   100-(abc)       100
1   qwe-100-(abc)   1001
3   xyz             300
```

Comment: Thanks for the function isin. But it returns a partial output. Please check the expected result in the question.